# how to generate excel file from oracle reports apps ERP?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms, oraclereports, oracle-ebs

Form version : Oracle 10g

Report version : Oracle 10g

OS : Windows xp

Oracle APPS ERP

I have report need to generate via excel by click button in the oracle form The existing reports are in pdf format. I tried to find something, but I couldn't succeed

Comment: Why not use XML BI Publisher. It is part of EBS, and most importantly it is preferred reporting tool than Oracle Reports as far as EBS is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

`DESFORMAT = DELIMITED` should do the job. It won't create a native Excel file, but - delimited files (such as a CSV) are easily read by MS Excel.

There's no any *code* to do that - `DESFORMAT` is one of reports' system parameters. You'll find it in

```
Object Navigator > Data Model > System Parameters > DESFORMAT
```

Comment: Can you provide me sample code. I am a beginner in this field

Comment: I've posted some more info; have a look.